# Prove every homomorphism of an odd cycle into itself is a bijection.

Tags: graph-theory

This comes straight from problem 1.5 (p. 12) of *Handbook of Product Graphs, Second Edition* by Hammack, Imrich, and Klavžar.

It even comes with a hint in the appendix:

> **Exercise 1.5** Hint: Show that the homomorphic image of an odd cycle is a closed walk that contains an odd cycle.

But I think maybe there's a misprint in the question or I'm missing some important nuance in how to think about cycles or the range of the homomorphism. Had the problem statement said *onto* instead of *into* I think I would agree, but I've double and triple checked the text and the errata at http://imrich.at/wp-content/uploads/Misprints_and_Notes-3.pdf.

I'm assuming that the set mapped *into* by homomorphism $\varphi$ is a set of $2k+1$ distinct vertices: $\{ u_1, u_2, \dots, u_{2k+1} \}$, with the original cycle $C_{2k+1}$ being $u_1u_2\dots{}u_{2k+1}u_1$, and a mapped cycle being a subsequence of the closed walk $\varphi(u_1)\varphi(u_2)\dots\varphi(u_{2k+1})\varphi(u_1)$. But I think there are easy counterexamples to a homomorphism $\varphi$ being a bijection: is it not true that $$\varphi:C_{2k+1} \rightarrow C_{2l+1}$$ permits a (non-bijective) homomorphism whenever $k \gt l$? (Essentially, have $\varphi$ "fold back" an even number of adjacent edges along the cycle; e.g., let $\varphi(u_3) = \varphi(u_1)$, $\varphi(u_4) = \varphi(u_2)$, and otherwise $\varphi(u_i) = u_{i-2}$, which essentially becomes $\varphi:C_{2k+1} \rightarrow C_{2k-1}$. All the vertices and edges are contained in those of the larger cycle, so shouldn’t this qualify as a legal mapping?)

I also have a subquestion: are the authors requiring that it be an *odd* cycle in order to avoid the possibility of a $u_1{}u_2{}u_1$ situation, so that the closed walk must contain a proper cycle?

---

So, reconsidering this after Misha's response below, I think the key thing I missed is that what I thought was a homomorphism wasn't. In my particular example, since $u_{2k+1}u_1$ is an edge in the original graph ($C_{2k+1}$), then if $\varphi$ is a homomorphism it **must** be the case that $\varphi(u_{2k+1})\varphi(u_1)$ is an edge in $C_{2k+1}$, but that would mean $u_{2k-1}u_1$ is an edge, which is false.

(Now at this point it seems the only homomorphisms from $C_n$ to $C_n$ would involve cyclically shifting indexes or reversing the direction cycled, or both.)

Comment: If we're talking about a homomorphism of an odd cycle into *itself*, then we must have $k=l$. There are non-bijective homomorphisms $\phi \colon C_{2k+1} \to C_{2l+1}$ when $k>l$, but they're homomorphisms from an odd cycle to a different odd cycle.

Comment: Okay. I think my mistake is in thinking only of the set of vertices $V(C_n)$ but ignoring that the structure $E(C_n)$ is also part of the definition of what’s being mapped into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think this is easiest for me by recognizing first that, for any homomorphism $\varphi: C_{2k+1} \rightarrow C_{2k+1}$, it must be the case that $\left(\varphi(v_{i+1}) - \varphi(v_i)\right) \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{2k+1}$, since edges must map to edges. (For vertices that increase in the clockwise direction, consider the sign positive; negative for counterclockwise.)

Then, consider possible values of $S$, defined as $$S = \sum_{i=1}^{2k+1} \varphi(i+1) - \varphi(i).$$ We know that $$S \bmod (2k+1) = \varphi(2k+2) - \varphi(1) = \varphi(1) - \varphi(1) = 0,$$ since we have a telescoping sum with vertices wrapping around clockwise from $2k+1$ back to $1$.

Since this is a cycle of odd length, $S$ must be $\pm (2k+1)$: it cannot be 0, because that would imply an equal number of $+1$ and $-1$ values, which could only be true if the cycle were of even length.

Thus, when mapping from an odd cycle to an odd cycle of the same length, any homomorphism must transit the mapped cycle once fully in either the clockwise or counterclockwise direction.

(If it were even length, we *could* go alternately forward/backward, essentially folding the original graph onto fewer edges in the destination and not wind up with a final illegal mapped edge.)

So from here, it's pretty easy to define bijections and see that they’re really the only choices for valid homomorphisms in the given structure: pick a start node and consistently proceed either clockwise or counterclockwise with adjacent vertices. There are therefore $2 * (2k+1)$ possible choices of bijections.